# How to do equal to data returned from php to android client using eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to develo[p an Android app. the app sends the user name and password to the php (server side), if the user doesn't exists it returns "not found"....

for now I don't want to use json :-)

my problem is that i can't do EQUAL to the retur string !!!! it's not working

```
if(text=="not found") ShowMessage("Invalid user and password !!");
```

or

```
if(text==getResources().getString(R.string.wronguser))
    ShowMessage("Invalid user and password !!");
```

and I tried the .equal(..) function BUT it's not work....

When I assign the return vale to textview it show me "not found" so why the == OR .equal doesn't work????

My php using UTF-8 encoding...THANX :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java strings should be compared using `.equals`. (`==` performs an identity comparison, while `.equals` compares actual content.)

So start by changing

```
if (text=="not found") ...
```

to

```
if (text.equals("not found")) ...
```

etc.

If that doesn't seem to work, make sure the strings doesn't contain unexpected leading / trailing white-space. You may also want to ignore case:

```
if (text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("not found")) ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working here is my code:                  if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("not found"))    ShowMessage("Invalid user and password !!");

Comment: I have checked the length and I found it 10 !!!!! instead of 9 so must be a special char in the string, how I remove extra chars:-)

Comment: Doesn't `trim()` work? You could change `equals` to `contains` if that's good enough.